# Windows Azure Platform, latest version?

Tags: .net, sql-server, azure, cloud

I searched through internet but found nothing. The whitepapers of Windows Azure Platform say something like that:

> In its first release, the maximum size
>   of a single database in SQL Azure
>   Database is 10 gigabytes
>
> A few things are omitted in the
>   technology’s first release, however,
>   such as the SQL Common Language
>   Runtime (CLR) and support for spatial
>   data. (Microsoft says that both will
>   be available in a future version.)

I want to know that Microsoft had updated Windows Azure Platform and removed these limits or not?

I decided to post this question here instead of Serverfault.com because it's more relative to programming than administration.

Thank you

Comment: +1 to Phani Kumar PV - 50GB is just around the corner for SQL Azure. Just to clarify something though: SQL Azure does not equate to "Windows Azure platform." There's also Compute instances, table and blob storage (which are for massive-scale storage well beyond SQL Azure's capacity), AppFabric with service bus and access control, and Content Delivery Network.

Answer (score 2):

Microsfot havent removed the limtis yet. But more flexibility and features are added to it. Follwoing is a quick glimpse of what they are.

At Mix Microsoft announced that theywill be offering a new 50gb size option in June. If you would like to become an early adopter of this new size option before generally available, send an email to EngageSA@microsoft.com  and it will auto-reply with instructions to fill out a survey to nominate your application that requires greater than 10gb of storage.

Other announcements included:

MARS in April: Execute multiple batches in a single connection
Spatial Data in June: Geography and geometry types
SQL Azure Labs: SQL Azure Labs provides a place where you can access incubations and early preview bits for products and enhancements to SQL Azure. Currently OData Service for SQL
Azure.

Following are  the links for the same

http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlazure/archive/2010/03/19/9981936.aspx

second Link

http://ukazure.ning.com/

Answer (score 0):

Propose and/or Vote for the SQL Azure features you want, e.g. " the SQL Common Language Runtime (CLR)" or "50GB is not enough," at http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com/pages/34685-sql-azure-feature-voting